# Writing a matrix for a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble understanding the details involved in writing the matrix when given a linear map. I feel the problems can have many details but the answers are instantaneous and unclear.

Consider this problem:

Let $U \leq V, U \neq V, V \neq \{0\}$

Let $u_1,.....,u_k$ be basis of $U$

Extend to the basis

$u_1,....,u_k,v_1,....,v_l$ of $V$.

(a) Define $S\in \mathscr{L}(U,V)$ by $Su = U$. Find $\mathscr{M}(S)$

(b)Define $T\in \mathscr{L}(V,U)$ by $Tu_i = a_i$ and $Tv_j = 0$. Find $\mathscr{M}(T)$.

The solutions given were

(a)

```
 |10......0|

 |01......0|

 |001.....0|
 .
 |00......1|
 .
 .
 |000.....0|
```

(b)

```
|1......00|
|010....00|
|001....00|
.
. 
.
|000...100|
```

I think for (a) we have a k by l matrix, and gives the diagonal of k by k over zero. Further details I am unsure. For (b)  we get the l by k matrix and the right to columns are zeros. Since  $Tv_j = 0$  must be involved somehow to make this true.

Comment: what are your thoughts in this problem?

Comment: For the first one, see the range is $U$ only so consider the basis of $U$. For the second one, you all ready know that $Tv_j=0$ so $v_i$s are not going to effect.